# Type identifiers at runtime

Tags: c#, types, runtime, identifier

The following isn't possible.

```
var dataType = Type.GetType("System.String");

//magic here

var hs = new HashSet<dataType>();
```

The above result in the error: The type or namespace name 'dataType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is there some magic in the middle to make it work? If not, what are workable approaches to achieve the intended goal? Thank you.

Edit: Was trying to be helpful by being brief, but I need to provide more detail.

Let's say we have something like this:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
}
```

And let's assume the serialized object type was stored as a string. How do we deserialize with the type as a string. I have a few work arounds in mind, but was hoping there was something involving runtime type identifiers I was unfamiliar with.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that. C#

Comment: Trick question?  Can't you use `HashSet<object>()`?

Comment: what's your "intended goal"?

Comment: Goal is to be able to use a type identity at runtime. The above was the briefest example I could thing of that would illustrate the problem without bulking up the question with the details of what specifically I'm doing.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get to that is:

```
object hs = Activator.CreateInstance(
       typeof(HashSet<>).MakeGenericType(dataType));
```

However, this is **really** hard to use - there is no particularly usable non-generic API exposed by `HashSet<T>`, so I would consider thinking about *what* you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Best I think you can do is:

```
var dataType = Type.GetType("System.String");

// This is your magic.
var hst = typeof(HashSet<>).MakeGenericType(dataType);
var hs = (IEnumerable)Activator.CreateInstance(hst);  
var add = hst.GetMethod("Add");
```

(`IEnumerable` being the only sorta useful non-generic interface implemented by `HashSet<T>`)

now, add items:

```
add.Invoke(hs, new object[] { "Test 1" });
add.Invoke(hs, new object[] { "Test 2" });
add.Invoke(hs, new object[] { "Test 3" });
add.Invoke(hs, new object[] { "Test 1" });
```

So you can `foreach` over it, but it's still pretty useless as you get back `object`s again. You *could* then possibly try `dynamic` and duck-type the item:

```
foreach (dynamic item in hs)
{
    // item.Length would work here, for instance.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that @Marc Gravell didn't suggest this I'm guessing there is something wrong with this, but you could try something like this:

```
public class HashSetGenerator
{
    public static HashSet<T> GetHashSet<T>(T testType) 
    {
        return new HashSet<T>();
    } 
}
```

You can then generate the HashSet like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HashSet<string> stringHash = HashSetGenerator.GetHashSet("string");
    HashSet<int> intHash = HashSetGenerator.GetHashSet(123);
}
```